# Background colour showing in IE .Help me to remove that colour?

Tags: internet-explorer, background

In my site, i have a scrolling feedback box(to the right side of the page). Everything works fine except in IE, that feedback box shows a white background. I tried setting "background-color" to transparent also. But the issue is still there.

Link: http://www.akashbc.com

Please help me to find the exact thing that is causing this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: @Theraot please don't make pointless edits to old questions, it bumps them back up to the top of the list when they are really old

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? How are you making it transparaent?

In your ViewSource, the background is commented out:

```
<div id ="fbcont" style="width: 235px;

margin-left: 33px;

padding-top: 64px;

font-family: calibri;

font-size: 15px;

color: white;/*background-color: transparent;*/">
```

One one to go, the least troublesome way IMHO, is to use RGBA

```
background: rgb(200, 54, 54); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0);
```

Note the fallback colour for non compliant browsers (that's IE8 and back, FF2 and back, Safari 2 and back and any Netscape).
For IE 7/8 you can try this

```
<!--[if IE]>

   <style type="text/css">

   .color-block {
       background:transparent;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);
       zoom: 1;
    } 

    </style>

<![endif]-->
```

Another way is to use a transparent PNG (but IE7 is lousy and rendering png's).

Or use opacity (filter for IE) and then layer with a second div so content can be see (opacity affects the wholke thing , not just background).

Comment: Sorry , i am not able to follow you.Could you make it easier for me and tell me what exactly i have to do?

Comment: My ie version is 8 by the way

Comment: Try: <!--[if lt IE 9]>background:transparent;       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);zoom: 1;
<![endif]--><!--[if !IE]> -->background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
<![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]>background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);<![endif]-->

Comment: BTW the reason it happens is because Microsoft did not follow the same standards as other browser makers up to IE8 (IE7 just sucked really to!) and IE8 still had some of those hangovers (but much better). IE9 pretty much conforms. This is the hell that us WedDevs have had to put up with for decades now.

Comment: OK thanks..but it is now showing a black gradient instead of white..so how do i make the gradient transparent, i dont want any colour..

Comment: If you are now getting a solid colour, then it is falling back. In IE8 it should have taken the gradient as the transparancy colour and made it transparent. Make sure you have typed everything correctly. If so, try changing the stuff between the <!--[if lt IE9]> blocks with "opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);" (no quotes). If this workds, you may need to put the gradient back in for lt 7 (i.e. put a new block up front with <!--[if lt IE7]>...<![endif]>